# Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming and i had this problem coming up, whenever i use Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) to attack with my character, it fires maybe 3 out of 10 times,
i tried changing many variables and trying to put the code in diferent places but i couldn't find the fix to it

here's the code :

```
private void Update()
{
    dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") ;

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed * dirX , rb.velocity.y) ;

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && (IsGrounded()))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x,jumpForce,0);
    }
    
    UpdateAnimationState();

    if(attackTime <= 0)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            anim.SetBool("attacking", true);
            Collider2D[] enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll( attackLocation.position, attackRange, enemies );
            for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToDamage.Length; i++)
            {
                enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<Enemy_health>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }

        attackTime = startTimeAttack;
    }   
    else
    {
        attackTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        anim.SetBool("attacking", false);
    }

    if(attackTime <= 0)
    {
        if( Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            if(rb.velocity.y > .01f || rb.velocity.y < -.01f)
            {
                anim.SetBool("jumpattacking", true);
                Collider2D[] damage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll( attackLocation.position, attackRange, enemies );
                for (int i = 0; i < damage.Length; i++)
                {
                    Destroy( damage[i].gameObject );
                }
            }
        }

        attackTime = startTimeAttack;
    }   
    else
    {
        attackTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        anim.SetBool("jumpattacking", false);
    }
}

private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(attackLocation.position, attackRange);
}
```

Comment: What's the value of startTimeAttack? I would suspect there is some issue with your attackTime approach. You seem to only attack when "attackTime" is below 0 , set it to a value and immediately in the next frame set the animation to false. You may try using a Trigger instead of a Bool to activate the animation and let it run for it's full duration everytime you hit the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How should the `jumpattacking` case be ever reached?

- Either the `attackTime` is higher than `0` or the first `attacking` case already kicks in and sets `attackTime = startTimeAttack` immediately - **regardless of the input**!

  → You rather want to start the cooldown only if you actually attacked!
- And then still the `jumpattacking` could not be reached because the `attacking` case already consumes your input first and sets the timer.
- Finally the way you are using the animator Bool parameters looks like you would be better using [Tigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html) instead which is used for one time changing to a certain state and reset the trigger.

  I don't know how your animator is configured but it might be that since you immediately reset the bool parameters in the next frame it immediately transitions back to the idle state.

What you should probably do is rather merging both cases together like e.g.

```
private void Update()
{
    dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") ;

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed * dirX , rb.velocity.y) ;

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce, 0);
    }
    
    UpdateAnimationState();

    if(attackTime <= 0)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            // simply store this in a variable instead of implementing the same code twice
            // Use the absolute to simply check the magnitude regardless of the sign
            var isJumping = Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) > 0.01f;

            // Use ternary for switching between the two bools according to the isJumping
            anim.SetBool(isJumping ? "jumpattacking" : "attacking", true);
            // disable the according other bool (?)
            // As said rather using Trigger would already solve this
            //anim.SetBool(isJumping ? "attacking" : "jumpattacking", false);
            var enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackLocation.position, attackRange, enemies);
            foreach (var enemy in enemiesToDamage)
            {
                // again decide for the resulting action according to isJumping
                if(isJumping)
                {
                    Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
                }
                else
                {
                    enemy.GetComponent<Enemy_health>().TakeDamage(damage);
                }
            }

            // You only want to do this once you actually consumed the User input
            attackTime = startTimeAttack;
        } 
    }   
    else
    {
        attackTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        // rather using Trigger parameters wold make these unnecessary
        anim.SetBool("attacking", false); 
        anim.SetBool("jumpattacking", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i didn't think about this solution, i will implement it right away <3

edit : i implemented it and yet it still has the same issue 0_0 is it maybe due to lag or something ?